Grounding RFID reader hard casing to reduce interference?
I am using an Invengo XCRF807 RFID reader to write and read extremely small RFID tags (Murata LXMS21NCMH-230). Writing such tags is difficult as they need to be within mm of my antennae. The Invengo reader casing has a grounding bolt on it.
Would grounding the casing of the reader decrease potential interferences from the environment and contribute to writing data more reliably onto the tags?

Using a proper ground will reduce noise, but more-so it will improve the performance of the antenna.
Further discussion on why really belongs on the EE StackExchange: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453061/rfid-reader-sensitivity-read-range-how-does-a-hard-ground-increase-sensitivi

The reader has a grounding bolt because the designer decreed it was necessary.  So it stands to reason that the reader should work better if you wire it correctly.
